# CSS strange problem - showing differently when browser width change

Tags: html, css

i have find a strange problem. Please take a look to my picture where i try to explain the problem:

[image: picture]

Why the browser is showing this problem at changeing the viewport i dont know. i just know at moment that if i delete "margin: 0 auto;" for the HTML element "#topbox" then it dont do this, it stops to show different style for the dropdown menue, but how to position my HTML element "#topbox" in the middle without css statement "margin auto" is maybe the question at moment, its all so strange like often with css.

I have here my HTML and CSS code if you want to try this out:

```css
#topbox {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:100px;
 border: 5px solid green;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
#ContactSymbol {
 position:absolute;
 right:15px;
 top:25px;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 color:white;
 font-size:20px;
 padding:7px;
 border-radius:50px;
 border: 1px solid white;
}
.dropdown-content { 
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  top: 31px;
  background-color: #003A7E;
  border-radius: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border: 0.5px solid #00007E;
  min-width: 268px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0.9em;
  text-align:left;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor:default;
}
#ContactSymbol:hover .dropdown-content {
  display:block;
}
.DropdownUeberschrift {
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:blue;
  padding:7px;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 0;
}
.DropdownEintrag {
  display:block;
  padding:8px;
  font-size:0.85em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="test">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="background:#003A7E">
<div id="topbox">
  <div id="ContactSymbol">Phone
    <p class="dropdown-content">
   <span class="DropdownUeberschrift">Kontakt</span>
   <span class="DropdownEintrag">Telefon: 121768</span>
 </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this css:**

```
<style>
#ContactSymbol{
  font-size: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have try it, but id does not change the problem. This is a strange behavior, i just need to change the browser windows, if i make the broswer window a little bit smaller or bigger then i get always different results from the dropdown. Sometimes the dropdown mnue goes 1 pixel to right and sometimes it goes 1 pixel to much to left side.really strange think and only when i delete the "margin auto" css statement for "#topbox" element then this problem sops. but anyway i need also to bringt the "#topbox" element to the middle with "margin auto"

Comment: i dont know if you did had some time to try this yourself, because i am maybe not so good with my english in trying to explain it, but it can be worth somethink when this problem is knowed for any other future developments with css.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like i have find the solution for this strange problem, it was maybe just a fout in my CSS, i had used this wrong css statement "border: 0.5px solid #00007E;" it looks like 0.5px is a wrong value, because when i write 1px i see that the problem dont happen anymore.

Comment: can a border really be half a pixel?

Comment: i dont know, it did draw a border when i was using 0.5 pixel but this problem which i did try to explain was happen, now with 1 pixel border value it looks right.